# python replace name for different random names

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace the sentences with different name and I do not know why it is does works

```
text="hi, my name is angle enrico, how is everything going?"
s = text.replace(r'hi, my name is\s+','')
print(s)
```

I want to have an output 'how is everything going?',but I am getting'hi, my name is angle enrico, how is everything going?' 
Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: if the *rule* you are trying to code is *remove "hi, my name is angle enrico, "* then `text.replace("hi, my name is angle enrico,", "")`

Comment: I have different sentences with a lot of different names, that what I am doing \s+ instead of the name

Comment: Uncommon use, can you get more sample input and expect output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use regex syntax in a non-regex context. What your code is currently doing is searching for the literal string `hi, my name is\s+`, which clearly does not exist in your input string.

What you need to do is write a regex that will capture the beginning of the string, and then pass that into the `text.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
s = text.replace('hi, my name is','')
print(' '.join(s.split()[2:]))
```

Or:

```
print(text.split(', ')[2])
```

Both reproduce:

```
how is everything going?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text="hi, my name is angle enrico, how is everything going?"
>>> pre = text[text.index("hi, my name is ")+len("hi, my name is "):]
>>> pre
'angle enrico, how is everything going?'
>>> suf = pre[pre.index(", ")+len(", "):]
>>> suf
'how is everything going?'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a regex and the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

You want to replace the part of the string starting with 'Hi, my name is', followed by anything (`.*`), then a comma and at least one space (`,\s+`).

If the end of the sentence can contain commas as well, you need to take the smallest possible 'anything', so you have to do it in a non-greedy way (`.*?`).

So, you could do:

```
import re

text="hi, my name is angle enrico, how is everything going?"

s = re.sub(r'hi, my name is .*?,\s+', '', text)
print(s)
#how is everything going?
```

It also works with a second comma further in the sentence:

```
text="hi, my name is fred,   I'm fine, thanks!"
s = re.sub(r'hi, my name is .*?,\s+', '', text)
print(s)
#I'm fine, thanks!
```